# How to do a ManyToMany Association with 2 databases with Doctrine/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have have two databases : `base1` and `base2`, and two tables : `base1.client` and `base2.vehicule` that are associated via `base1.client_vehicule`. I need to access the "vehicules" associated to a "client" in the Client entity. I already have this :

src/Entity/Base1/Client.php

```
namespace App\Entity\Base1;

use App\Entity\Base2\Vehicule;

class Client
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Vehicule::class, inversedBy="client_vehicule")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="client_vehicule",
     *     joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_client", referencedColumnName="idClient")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_vehicule", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    private $vehicule;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->vehicule = new ArrayCollection();
    }
...
}
```

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
 orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: base1_em
        entity_managers:
            base1_em:
                connection: base1
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    Base1:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Base1'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Base1'
                        alias: Base1
            base2_em:
                connection: base2
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    Base2:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Base2'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Base2'
                        alias: Base2
```

The main problem is that Doctrine uses the default Entity Manager to get `Vehicules` in `Client`, but I also don't know how to properly join the three tables.

Comment: I don't think you can use two databases in 1 ORM model. Maybe you can do it with DBAL and some custom queries, but this sounds like a too complicated model for Doctrine ORM. Can you share some details about your use case?

Comment: What kind of details do you mean ?

Comment: Why can't you use one database for all tables? Are they one the same server?

Comment: They are on the same server but their purpose is different. I would say that base1 stores the data that is sent from the website and that base2 stores data to be used on the website (vehicles information for example). I don't have the possibility to merge the two.

Comment: I think this just isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you, at least I won't lose any more time trying to figure it out !

Comment: It's not really adivsed,you simply fetch the data you need and actually use code to glue them, read ip if you still wanna do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150320/symfony4-doctrine-cross-database-joins-configuration